# Responsive Table in Bootstrap with Vertical Headings

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4, responsive

I got a problem with Bootstrap responsive table: while it works great for tables with horizontal headings, I can't achieve what I want with my vertical headings table.

I have lots of 2-column tables for specifications that look like this:

```
<table class="table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <th>FRAME</th>
        <td>ALUMINUM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>POWER</th>
        <td>500W</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BATTERY</th>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>WEIGHT</th>
        <td>45KG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <td>333$</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On desktop there are no problems for visualization, but on smartphone, the text get mashed so that it's unreadable. What I'd like to do instead is retain like 30% of the width for the th, fill the 70% left with the td and if it's not enough, then expand on the right with scrolling like bootstrap already does for normal reponsive-tables.

Comment: can you post your css as well

Answer (score 0):

You can bootstrap media queries to add your personal styling

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  table-responsive th {
    width: 30%
  }

table-responsive td {
    width: 70%
  }
}

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  As per requirement, you can make changes for tablet as well
 }
```

Comment: I already have 30% for th and 70% for td globally, what I wanted is that when you are on a mobile device, instead of just taking 70% of screen width for showing the td, expand on the right side so with scroll right to make it more readable.

Comment: you can add your personal css in the first media query that will work on mobile devices. Increase the width of the element to your liking.

Comment: increasing the width alone doesn't create the horizontal scroll bar. i need to know how can i extend the secondo column to make it scrollable through an horizontal bar.

Comment: use overflow-x: scroll; That will do the job.